# When running 2 observables one after another, getting: Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, switchmap

I have 2 functions that return Observables that I would like to execute one after another.
**function1** return

```
Observable<SomeDataObject>
```

and **function2** return type

```
Observable<Any>
```

I want that the function that execute them return boolean based of the result of  **function1**.
I was managed to do so when running first **function1**, but now I would like to run **function2** first, and I get the error:

```
"Argument of type '(res: <SomeDataObject>) => boolean' is not assignable to 
 parameter of type '(value:SomeDataObject, index: number) => 
ObservableInput<any>. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 
ObservableInput<SomeDataObject>
```

See my code:
This **works**:

```
return this.someService.function1().pipe(
  switchMap(f1Result => 
  {
     this.someService.repositpry.f1ResultData = f1Result;
     return this.someService.function2().pipe(
        map(res => 
       {
           if (res) return true;
           else return false;
       }));
   })
 )
```

This **fails**:

```
 return this.someService.function2.pipe( 
  switchMap(f2Result => 
  {
      this.someService.function1().pipe(
       map(f1result => 
       {
           this.someService.repositpry.f1ResultData = f1Result;
       })
    );
    if (f2Result) return true
    else return false;
 }));
```

Comment: This may not be a switchmap issue but rather a type issue, make sure you are using correct types according to the interfaces you have.

Comment: @Ramesh - I've edited it - the types were included in the original question but were removed where not in a code block

Comment: where is this `(value:SomeDataObject, index: number) => 
ObservableInput<any>` coming from? looks like you are expecting two arguments but sending only one.

Comment: @Ramesh - switchMap(f2Result =>  is marked as problematic and this is the error when hovering it.

Comment: @Ramesh - Solved - see my solution

Comment: You just wasted time from several people by making typos in your question and not showing essential parts of the code. I know you [don't agree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522797/solved-when-running-2-observables-one-after-another-getting-result-based-on/60523237#comment107073246_60523237) but stackoverflow is not here to help you debug your code. And if you don't even copy paste the code correctly you need to work on your question quality.

Comment: And adding an answer to your question is also bad practice by the way. Would be also smart to "fix" the typos in the question, since the code from the answer is currently not matching your question.

Answer (score 1):

You do:

```
this.someService.function2.pipe(
  //...
)
```

Should it not be:

```
this.someService.function2().pipe(
  //...
);
```

Comment: Sorry - typo error - the code was not copied, but rewrite.

Comment: I don't agree - No need to show functio1 and function2 code as long as I describe their output type - the problem is with the structure of the flow and types mismatch

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, within the most external pipe, you have

```
this.someService.function1().pipe(
       map(f1result => 
       {
           this.someService.repositpry.f1ResultData = f1Result;
       })
```

`f1result` is an Observable. In the inner pipe you use a `map` operator. This is different from the first example, the one which is working, since in the first example you use `switchMap`, which flattens the Observable.

So you may have to use `switchMap` in the inner pipe as well, followed by a `map` to return the result you are looking for, something like this

```
return this.someService.function2.pipe( 
  switchMap(f2Result => 
  {
      this.someService.function1().pipe(
       switchMap(f1result => 
       {
           this.someService.repositpry.f1ResultData = f1Result;
       }.pipe(() => {
           if (f2Result) return true
           else return false;
       }))
    );
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a concatMap operator to do this.

```
return this.someService.function1().pipe(
  concatMap(f1Result => 
  {
     this.someService.repositpry.f1ResultData = f1Result;
     return this.someService.function2.pipe(
        map(res => 
       {
           if (res) return true;
           else return false;
       }));
   })
 )
```

Comment: This isn't answering my question : I need to execute function2() before function1.

Comment: its not the updated solution your following the promise way which can lead you to the callback hell. you should make a use of RXjs operator